# Is there any way to check a recently sold item's stats?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been putting rares I've found on  the auction house for cheap prices, which usually results in them being snatched up relatively quickly. Afterwards, I'd love to know what sold for the particular price to help gauge how much I can charge for future rares.

Is there anyway to see the stats of the item you just sold or can you only view the rare name and selling price?

[image: Screenshot of the completed tab in the auction house]

I'm basically asking if it is possible to see what the stats were on the Doom Conclave (for example) or if I should just note what the mods are somewhere else before selling rares.

Comment: It really bothers me that they do not have this functionality. It would be so freaking easy to implement... What on earth were they thinking?

Comment: Since Blizzard has been continuously adding features to improve the auction house in World of Warcraft, I'm optimistic that such a straightforward feature will be added to the Diablo III auction house in the future.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution from various other sites that has been going around:

> Make sure you do not send the gold you earned for the item to your
>   stash. Open up a chat console, type a message to anyone (even party if
>   there's no-one in your party), shift and click the little icon next to
>   the gold amount (same as when you're linking your friends to your
>   items in your inv), it will show the item you sold as a link in the
>   console which you can click on and see the stats of.

As of the 1.04 patch, it should be possible to just mouse over the item in your completed window to see its stats.

Comment: nice, very handy trick!

Comment: As of the 1.04 patch, it should be possible to just mouse over the item in your completed window to see its stats.

Comment: @bwarner as of months ago, like 90% of people stopped playing Diablo 3. -.-

Comment: @Decency Well, 100% of me is still playing :)

Answer (score 5):

This is possible after patch 1.0.4.

From the release notes:

> Tooltips have been added for items in the Completed tab

This is a screenshot from my completed tab

[image: Screenshot showing item hover (with stats) for a Rare Shield]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there's no way (that I've found) to view the stats on bought or sold rare items without having access to the item itself (obviously only feasible in the bought case).