# How can I see what my item was sold for at Auction?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to check a recently sold item's stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68692/is-there-any-way-to-check-a-recently-sold-items-stats)

I'm trying to get an idea of pricing so I can get the most value out of any future items that I'll sell. I don't put more than a minute or two into each item so it would be nice to get some feedback on how long it took for items to sell, how much interest there was in it, etc.

I notice that items have "Order ID's" but I can't find anywhere to put this to use to actually get information about the auctions.

So, for example, how can I get information about the three sold items below: 
[image: my sold items]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell how long your item took before it sold itself on the Auction House, or how much interest was generated in your item (reason being that the interest generation would be hard to prove because the AH displays all the items in a whole page).

However, there's the Date available for you to gauge which day it sold and how much did you gain (after the transaction fee) in gold in that particular transaction.

Order IDs would actually be used in case an item did not process correctly and the buyer/seller ended up not getting the item/gold respectively.

Also, if you want to gauge on the pricing, why not see what others are putting their items up for in the Auction House respectively?

However, your approach (1 to 2 minutes on deciding pricing, etc) on the Auction House would be insufficient for you to gauge how much you would want to price your item at.

If you really want to milk every cent out of the item's value, you need to start researching and pricing your items competitively. This is how it also works in the real world, companies price their items based on competitors and value-added services via research itself.

Or you could just price it randomly, and see if any sucker buys it at that price (sometimes people are desperate for an item. :P).

Comment: I really just want to know what the item was. I put ~8 items up for roughly the same price (5000 starting, 10-15k buyout) and some of them sold and some didn't. No doubt some are underpriced or overpriced, but I don't really care: it's still better than me salvaging them. I just want to know what "Marksman's Doctrine" actually did so I can value similar things higher in the future.

Comment: As for interest generation, I just mean how many people bid on it.

Comment: Hmm, its just not possible as of right now. Maybe you could suggest this to the developers, they could be able to implement it if they think its viable.

Comment: As for bidding, same thing i guess. Because as of now, the highest bidder wins. Collecting information on who bid on which item and for how much may be too much textual data for Blizzard to want to collect. Or maybe its part of their plans in future patches. Who knows? Like i said, the only way is to submit feedback. (Also, if you wanna close this chapter and move on, remember to select an answer, or offer a bounty.)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it in a spreadsheet along with time of placed item, sold for, profit made, etc.  I have one built that I use for all my auctioneering.