# Diablo 3 AH - see item stats after item sold

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to check a recently sold item's stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68692/is-there-any-way-to-check-a-recently-sold-items-stats)

Is it possible to see the item stats of item I just sold in the auction house? It would be nice to now the values afterwards to see which items sell, why and for what reason (in comparison to others). Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to view the item after it has sold. All you have to do is:

1.Press enter to bring up the chat window(does not matter who you send the message to)

2.Shift+Click on the stack of gold.

Click on the item in the chat window and you can view the generic stats of the item that just sold.

Very Similar to this Question:
[Is there any way to check a recently sold item's stats?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68692/is-there-any-way-to-check-a-recently-sold-items-stats)

*Note: You must view the item before sending the gold to the stash for this to work.

Comment: This didn't work for me though

Comment: @JQAn I was just able to do it last night. Did you click on the icon next to the gold? Also, it has to be before you send the gold to the stash. Once it is in the stash, it becomes no longer possible

Comment: I will try it again to be sure